# iPhone Cache Manifest setup

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events, manifest

I've been trying to setup a cache manifest for an iPhone WEB Application. I have included:

```
<html manifest="speed.manifest">
```

However, something isn't working. I have configured easyPhp to deliver manifest with the mime.types file and also added AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest to the httpd.conf to try this also. It unfortunately doesn't work.

I am using this:

```
var appCache = window.applicationCache;
appCache.ondownloading = downloadingFunction();
appCache.onerror = errorFunction();
```

Both of these functions get called. Inside the `errorFunction`, I alert the event.type which is "load". I don't know why this would be... I think everything is right since I have managed this with other projects in the past. Any help on working out where the problem lies would be appreciated. I think there's probably still a problem in my easyPhp because the rest of the code is the same as in my other projects but I can't be 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your web app in Google Chrome, open the Developer tools and ensure the console is visible.

You should see appear a good logging of what happens with the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Cache manifest simply doesn't work in UIWebView on IOS 3.x
It works on UIWebView and Mobile Safari on IOS 4.x